# Relational table data read on Vue with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have USER & ROLE Table

I want to show the role of that particular user on his datatable which is in Vue.

***All the related codes are given on those links.***

Thanks in Advance.

PLEASE MENTION IF YOU KNOW ABOUT ANY VIDEOS/TUTORIALS ON THIS TOPIC

Vue Code link: https://notepad.pw/code/nqxo2q43

Roles Table: https://notepad.pw/code/n3zw1m9jh

Users Table: https://notepad.pw/code/5yrleots

Role Model:  https://notepad.pw/code/o853sl6fv

User Model:  https://notepad.pw/code/f00vu7m1

Role Controller: https://notepad.pw/code/w773twp2p

User Controller: https://notepad.pw/code/4vzarmyk

Comment: Hi - welcome to Stack Overlflow. A few things: 

- Firstly - posting links to pastes of code generally isn't that useful - as you might as well be posting them here. 
- Consider posting a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) link - as that is fully interactive.
- But a fully coded example isn't as useful as just boiling your question down to it's simplest reproduction.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't know that.

I am trying to upload it on Codebox and edit the post